# Regular Expression for Password

Tags: regex, password-protection

I need help creating a password regex.
A password must contain at least 4 characters, letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers and special characters - no spaces.

msn like regular expression.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Define *special characters*. Also tell us what regular expression engine you are using.

Comment: Hey im trying to submit a form but firstly test with jquery for valid input then parse to php also test there.
So i want to have a password containing letters uppercase or lowercase at least 4 chars long numbers and special chars ! @ # $ % ^ & * ();,.+-

Answer (score 0):

This regex works - see test data and output below:

```
^(?=.{4,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[@#$%^&+=i.,!?:;*/])
```

Test data in passwords.txt (only the first should pass):

```
aB#1
aB #1
ab#1
AB#1
aB#a
aB1a
aB1

mac-osx> grep -P '^(?=.{4,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.* )(?=.*[@#$%^&+=i.,!?:;*/])' passwords.txt
aB#1
```

You can add whatever extra "special characters" you need into the last look ahead regex's character class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[#&*%])^\S*$
```

If letter may be any Unicode letter, you can use this regex:

```
(?=.*?\p{Ll})(?=.*?\p{Lu})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[#&*%])^\S*$
```

To add special characters, simply put them inside `[]`

Answer (score -1):

try that

```
^.*(?=.{4,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

Comment: Remove the first `.*` and the last `.*$` (add at least `.,!?:;*/-` to special chars).