# Password Strength Pattern

Tags: php, passwords, design-patterns

Should I use a password pattern like a-zA-Z0-9 and also require at least one of each character class in the password, or simply allow anything inside the password?

What do sites allow the user to use as his/her password? Is there anything else I should consider?

Comment: **Nevermind, misread the question** - What is the password for? What sort of users do you expect to have? Password requirements should be set up to best serve the people using the passwords. I'd expect much higher restrictions for an internet banking site than I would for a forum, for example.

Comment: I want to be able to use a password like `éâ!@#!@#∑åß∂` - don't mark it as unsafe because it doesn't have `a-zA-Z0-9`.

Comment: Speaking in regex-lingo: `'/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_!@#$%^&*().]{10,25}$/'` you could let your user create a password that starts with a letter from the alphabet, followed by some acceptable characters, then request a minimum of 10 and a maximum of 25 characters

Comment: I think im going with this: at least 6 characters, 1 upper case, 1 lower case and 1 number.I think these requirements will be fine.

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a-ZA-Z0-9 is overly limited. You should let me use any characters, and enforce **minimum** requirements (i.e. at least 8 characters, at least one letter and one number)

Comment: @Iarsmans I'd generally include a punctuation requirement, yeah, but if he's proposing a-zA-Z0-9 that may be too strict for his client.

Answer (score 3):

## Password Entropy

The test of a good password is not the number of sets of characters represented but *Entropy*.

**Testing for Entropy:** The people at Dropbox have put together this fantastic tool called [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) to do just that. I would *highly recommend* reading their [write-up explaining it here](https://blogs.dropbox.com/tech/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/).

**Brief Explanation:** Both character classes (lower case, upper case, digits and special characters) and length are both important because together they raise password entropy (length does this much faster than character classes though) but users then tend toward predictable patterns which lowers entropy.

This may be humour but it helpfully illustrates part of the point:
http://xkcd.com/936/[image]

Answer (score 2):

There should be no limit to what the user should be able to use. Since you would hash the password before you store it anyways (i hope) this will make no difference what the password contain.

If you set requirements, they should be minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Password Regular Expression Pattern

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})
```

Breakdown

```
(                       # Start of group
  (?=.*\d)              #   must contains one digit from 0-9
  (?=.*[a-z])           #   must contains one lowercase characters
  (?=.*[A-Z])           #   must contains one uppercase characters
  (?=.*[@#$%])          #   must contains one special symbols in the list "@#$%"
              .         #     match anything with previous condition checking
                {6,20}  #        length at least 6 characters and maximum of 20 
)                       # End of group
```

Related:

- [Regular Expression for Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687894/regular-expression-for-password)

Comment: Please never, ever enforce a maximum password length.

Answer (score -1):

minimum 8 characters, preferable 12

at least one digit, at least one lower case, at least one upper case, at least one symbol (*/%...)

Comment: I don't think these can be treated as global requirements. Different use cases call for different minimum requirements.